# Problems with Flexbox in Safari (Bottom aligned items)

Tags: css, safari, sass, flexbox, ionic2

We have the following layout:

[image]

The layout shows the list (blue container) top aligned, but we need to make the list **bottom aligned**. We accomplished that by making the container (orange) `flex` and then we made the red container `flex: 1`, but it does not work in Safari.

The `scss` looks like that:

```
    .orange-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        .red-container {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .blue-container {
            // Nothing
        }
    }
```

in Safari, when the list grows, it overlaps the red container and the container above it (white box).

We already tried to add the `-webkit` vendor to our flex properties and nothing has changed.

I created a [git repo](https://github.com/dgroh/ionic-v2-long-lists-overlapping-content-above-it) to ilustrate the problem

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: what safari version?

Comment: 9.1.2 (El Capitan)

Comment: do you use any other declarations, such as min-width, etc? If so, please post all of it. I will try and replicating it on my enviroment.

Comment: No, that is all actually

Comment: It's hard to tell with such limited code. What does the HTML look like? Have you tried justify-content: space-between on the container? Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. Also, does your layout work in other browsers?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome and IE

Comment: Hi @AlexMacra please see the repo I created: https://github.com/dgroh/ionic-v2-long-lists-overlapping-content-above-it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by doing following:

```
.orange-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .red-container {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .blue-container {
        flex-shrink: 10;
    }
}
```

The `flex-grow` helped but didn't fix the problem in Safari. In Chrome and IE all was good, but in Safari the items were missing spaces which made the items to be very close to each other, so I solved this with `flex-shrink: 10`.

If this is the best solution, I don't know, but it solved the problem with Safari. I hope I still can get any feedback in this regard.

**EDIT:**

So after researching a bit more, I found out, that I could use `flex-schrink: 0` for those containers I wanted not to get messed up by the list, so that is the result:

```
.orange-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .white-container {
        flex-schrink: 0;
    }

    .red-container {
        flex-shrink: 0
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .blue-container {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```